# When can we release apps that use the Google SDK for iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store, google-plus

I've successfully integrated the Google+ SDK for iOS into my app, downloaded from here :

https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/

However the SDK is listed as begin in developer preview as per :

"Note: The Google+ platform for iOS is currently in Developer Preview."

Does anyone know if I can submit / release my app whilst this is in this mode or do I need to wait for Google to release it from the preview (which may take months!).

Thanks,

Steve H

Answer (score 2):

Applications that depend on [Google+ history API](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/#write_moments_to_google_history) should not be released to production. This is because Google+ history is only available for [developers](https://developers.google.com/+/history/preview/).

Other uses of the Google+ platform for iOS can be released to production.

Comment: Thanks, I'm not using history so that sounds encouraging!